# Error in -title : invalid argument to unary operator Execution halted

Tags: r, cron

I used CronJobs to schedule my R markdown to run everyday at 6pm. However, it did not run the script and gave me the following error:Error in -title : invalid argument to unary operator
Execution halted.

The work directory is set to my source location.

Any advice? Thanks!

Here is my code:

````
---
title: "EXAMPLECODE"
author: "XXXX"
date: "5/4/2020"
output: pdf_document
---

#STEP 1: INSTALL AND LOAD RCURL PACKAGE

```{r}
install.packages("RCurl")
library(RCurl)
```

#STEP 2: READ IN CSV FILE FOR EXAMPLE

```{r}
Example<- getURL("https://www.EXAMPLEURLHERE.csv")
ExampleData <- read.csv(text = Example)
ExampleData
```

#STEP 3: SAVE DATA INTO CSV FILE

```{r}
write.table(ExampleData, file="ExampleData_Update.csv", sep=",")
```
````

Comment: I think the error might be caused by a problem with your code. Perhaps if you include it in your question we could help to fix it?

Comment: Hi @AllanCameron, thanks for getting back to me so quickly! When you say code, do you mean something wrong with my R markdown code or something wrong with my CronJobs code? The reason I ask is because I did not write code for the CronJobs scheduler. I actually used the Add-in function that has me just fill out the information and hit create job. Do you think it is at all possible that it doesn't work because I'm doing it in DropBox?

Comment: If you look at @r2evans answer, you'll see the best guess that anyone is going to be able to make without more information (and it's actually pretty unusual for anyone to take the time to make such a helpful guess with the limited information provided). If you don't show us your R markdown code, then a guess is all anyone is going to be able to give you as to what might be wrong.

Comment: That's fair. I uploaded my code. It's quite a simple code. What do you think? Is it my script or my Cron Job operator?

Comment: It is neither the script nor the cron job operator. It is likely the cron job itself. It would be most useful (perhaps even resolving) to see the cron job itself.

Comment: Thank you for both of your time! I just resolved the issue! It turns out, my terminal was not grabbing the script for cron in the right locations. When I typed which Rscript in my terminal, it brought me to "/usr/local/bin/Rscript" However, it needed to go to my r project so I used "cd /Users/REST OF PATH HERE" and it worked!

Answer (score 7):

This error is common when you have a unary operator (e.g., `-`, `+`, or `!`) that is out of place. This indicates you have a typo or an object that is empty or not what you think. A *guess* (since you haven't responded to @AllanCameron's understated suggestion) is that you have a variable named `title` somewhere, assume that it is numeric or something you can index a vector/list/frame off of, and it is either non-numeric or empty. I can reproduce this precise error with

```r
title <- c()
mtcars[-title,]
# Error in -title : invalid argument to unary operator
title <- "1"
mtcars[-title,]
# Error in -title : invalid argument to unary operator
```

If you want a stack-trace on errors, then you might take a suggestion from https://renkun.me/2020/03/31/a-simple-way-to-show-stack-trace-on-error-in-r/:

```r
options(error = function() {
  sink(stderr())
  on.exit(sink(NULL))
  traceback(3, max.lines = 1L)
  if (!interactive()) {
    q(status = 1)
  }
})
mtcars[-title,]
# Error in -title : invalid argument to unary operator
# 2: `[.data.frame`(mtcars, -title, )
# 1: mtcars[-title, ]
```

In which case it tells you a little more. If it's in a function, that stack trace gives you the line number.

```r
myfunc <- function(title) {
  1+1 # doing something
  2*2 # doing something else
  3^3 # yawn
  mtcars[-title,]
}
myfunc(1:30)
#                mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
# Maserati Bora 15.0   8  301 335 3.54 3.57 14.6  0  1    5    8
# Volvo 142E    21.4   4  121 109 4.11 2.78 18.6  1  1    4    2
myfunc(c())
# Error in -title : invalid argument to unary operator
# 3: `[.data.frame`(mtcars, -title, ) at #5
# 2: mtcars[-title, ] at #5
# 1: myfunc(c())
```

(I know, `title` is mis-named here, just over-proving the point.)

(Just to assert again: I demonstrated on a `data.frame`, but this works with vectors/lists as well: `(1:10)[-title]`)

---

Further, upon seeing your "script": it is not a script. It is a document. If I'm correct, then you are calling this something like `Rscript /path/to/file.Rmd`. In that case, R thinks this is an R script file, not an R-markdown file.

Let's try this on the console. Copy the following (newline and all) and paste it into your R console:

```
---
title: "EXAMPLECODE"
```

When you see the "unary" error, you'll realize that R is interpreting this *as a command*. In a literal sense, R sees this as: "negate negate negate (newline/whitespace ignored) symbol(title) sequence-colon string(EXAMPLECODE)". (In)Conveniently, `title` is also a base function in R, so it exists; if it were instead

```
---
mytitle: "EXAMPLECODE"
```

(which is not valid Rmd), then your error would have instead read

```
Error: object 'mytitle' not found
```

which would have been slightly more clear/informative.

So ultimately I don't know for sure, but my guess is that you are inadvertently telling R to try to interpret the whole thing as an R script, *which it is not*. Perhaps `Rscript knitr::knit("/path/to/file.Rmd")` or similar will work instead.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough feedback! when I run my script manually everything works perfectly fine. In fact, it's a pretty simple script and I'll update it in my question right now. So I'm hesitant to believe that it is my script that is incorrect and not the CronJob operation itself. What do you think?

Comment: We still don't know how you are running your script, manually or within cron, so that (combined with knowing that it is an rmarkdown script) is likely going to seal-the-deal. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans, this helped me figure out how to force the package taskScheduleR to run my quarto .qmd as a scheduled task. I had to write an R script to render the .qmd, like: `# this is required for running the script as a scheduled task. Sys.setenv(QUARTO_PATH = 'C:/Program Files/RStudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/quarto.exe')  library(quarto) quarto_render("C:/Users/mypath/Download_upload_animal_locs.qmd")`

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else gets here, I scratched my head over this error for a ridiculously long time before I realized that I'd coded all the assignment operators in the script as '<--'.   I guess I got confused by some software's use of that as a shortcut to an arrow.
Should be -- obvious, I know, but I just have to say it: '<-'