# R Markdown knit issue: "Error in -title : invalid argument to unary operator"

Tags: r, r-markdown

Im new to R and R markdown, Im trying to run R Markdown code from a teamproject, but it doesnt run probably and I have problems understanding the errors.

```
title: "R"
Error in -title : invalid argument to unary operator
> output:
+   flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
+     orientation: columns
Error: object 'output' not found
>     vertical_layout: fill
Error: object 'vertical_layout' not found

{r setup, include=FALSE}
Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
library(flexdashboard)
library(rmarkdown)
library(knitr)
library(readxl)

Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
 {data-width=100}
Error in data - width = 100 : could not find function "-<-"
```

Comment: I tried to format your code, but it's unclear what it is that you've posted. Are the right arrows (`>`) actually in your document, or is that how the code printed to the console? Are there no backticks above and below your r code chunk? It would be better if you posted a representative snippet of the document itself, not console output

Comment: Hi imb! Can you please offer additional information about your code? Is there any error in your document? Are you knitting the document from any IDE, from R console or from a shell?. Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61624076/error-in-title-invalid-argument-to-unary-operator-execution-halted. Most of the times that error comes from an error in the code used to knit, knitting from the wrong directory, or perhaps any problem with the code in the document

Comment: Thank you for the replies! That is code printed to the console since there is where the errors are explained. @Jose I found out the problem comes because I'm knitting from the wrong directory. Do you have any suggestions how to change the directory of the dashboard?

Comment: I'm glad you found the problem. You can set the directory for any session using `setwd()`. You can check which directory is used in the session with `getwd()`

Answer (score 3):

The `YAML` header should be contained between `---`, the `R` code in chuncks starting and endding with ```` ``` ````, [see](https://pkgs.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/articles/flexdashboard.html).
Try to knit following `.Rmd` file :

````
---
title: "R"
output:
   flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
   orientation: columns
   vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(rmarkdown)
library(knitr)
library(readxl)
```

Your text here
````