# Error in -title : invalid argument to unary operator

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am not sure why I suddenly started getting this error (Error in -title : invalid argument to unary operator) when running my R Markdown file.

**My Markdown file looks like this:**.

```
--- 
title: "Bios653 HW1"
author: "Genevieve" 
date: "1/28/2022"
output: html_document
---
```

**My Console looks like this:** <\br>

```
> --- 
+ title: "Bios653 HW1"
**Error in -title : invalid argument to unary operator** 
> author: "Genevieve"  
Error: object 'author' not found  
> date: "1/28/2022"
Error in date:"1/28/2022" : NA/NaN argument 
In addition: Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion  
> output: html_document  
Error: object 'output' not found
> ---
```

Comment: Do you have something in your environment called "HW1" or "Bios653" or something similar? Sometimes, just restarting your RStudio session helps get rid of odd errors.

Comment: Hi Genevieve! Please offer additional information. Are you knitting the document from any IDE, from R console or from a shell?. Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61624076/error-in-title-invalid-argument-to-unary-operator-execution-halted. Most of the times that issue comes from an error in the code used to knit, knitting from the wrong directory, or perhaps any problem with the code in the document. Try to restart R, as suggested by John Polo, then open a new Rmarkdown document with a few lines of code and check if everything is ok

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are just running this with R, e.g. with `source`, instead of knitting the document.

Use `knitr::knit("FILENAME.Rmd")`. If you are using RStudio you can click the knit button

[image]